# TEST - Runtime Error SIGSEGV

Tags: c, runtime-error

please help me [Here is a problem of Codechef](http://codechef.com/problems/TEST) . And this is my submission:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define M 60

int main()
{
    int i,arr[M],input;
    int s=0;
    puts("Input:");
    for(i=0;;i++){
        scanf("%d",&input);
        if(input==42){
            scanf("%d");
            break;
        }
        else{
            arr[i]=input;
            s++;
            }
        }
    puts("Output:");
    for(i=0;i<s;i++){
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When i create the code it successfully ran with GCC 4.9.2, but when i submit this Codechef said that it has a runtime error. I tried but could not found the error. 
So
Please help me to find out the error ...

Comment: The link seems broken. Please add the problem here.

Comment: "404 Error Occured! Page could not be found". But the challenge is supposed to test *you*. Try making some test cases yourself with values at the limits of the problem's constraints, and see how it behaves. The debugger can help you.

Comment: Aside: are you sure you should be printing "Input:" and "Output:"? Print *exactly* what the problem tells you to. Your output is checked by a machine.

Comment: Your loop doesn't have a termination condition. I have no idea how it is supposed to work.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the termination condition is `if(input==42) {  scanf("%d"); break; }`

Comment: @WeatherVane It *might* be one... But if there is no such an input, `i` will overflow

Comment: @EugeneSh. generally true but such problems have constraints and guarantees so that you can make assumptions about some limits. If OP can't answer the problem, it matters little whether it is "Compilation error", "Wrong answer", "Seg fault" of "Time limit" although the reason will give a clue.

Comment: @WeatherVane I updated  the problem link.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank u very much for print advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the variable in the second scanf is missing